# Permanent RotationAnimation with Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, rotation, android-animation

For my application project, I planned a welcome activity that allows the user to choose a group of countries.
For that I have two buttons: the first one will allow a CardView containing 4 TextViews to rotate by 90° until the TexView of the country group is readable (the other Textviews will be oriented differently).
The code below works for a Texview, but my problem is the permanent effect of the rotation.

I added the line: `rotateanimation.setFillAfter(true)` that works well, but half!

If we launch a new Rotation, the animation starts from the beginning, while my goal is to extend by 90° this rotation, to make a complete turn.
Mainactivity:

```
package training.geography.rotation

import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.animation.Animation
import android.view.animation.RotateAnimation
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity

class MainActivity() : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val textView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.group1)

        val buttonrotate = findViewById<Button>(R.id.rotatebutton)

        val rotateanimation =  RotateAnimation(0f, 90f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, .5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, .5f)

        buttonrotate.setOnClickListener {

            rotateanimation.setDuration(1000)

            rotateanimation.setFillAfter(true)

            textView.setAnimation(rotateanimation)

            textView.startAnimation(rotateanimation)

        }

        val buttonchoose= findViewById<Button>(R.id.choosebutton)

        buttonchoose.setOnClickListener {

            val intent = Intent(this, TripleRecyclerView::class.java)

            startActivity(intent)

        }

    }

}
```

activity_main  xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout

    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"

    android:layout_height="match_parent"  >

<TextView android:id="@+id/group1"

          android:layout_width="220dp"

          android:layout_height="220dp"

          android:text="@string/countriesgroup1"

          app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"

          app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"

          app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"

          android:layout_marginLeft="8dp" android:layout_marginStart="8dp"

          app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"

          android:layout_marginEnd="8dp" android:layout_marginRight="8dp"

          android:layout_marginTop="128dp"

          app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.497"/>

<Button android:id="@+id/rotatebutton"

        android:text="Rotate to choose Group of Countries"

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"

        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"

        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/group1"

        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"

        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"

        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"

        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp" android:layout_marginStart="8dp"

        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"

        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp" android:layout_marginRight="8dp" />

<Button android:id="@+id/choosebutton"

        android:text="Choose Group"

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"

        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"

        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/rotatebutton"

        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"

        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"

        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"

        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp" android:layout_marginRight="8dp"

        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"

        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"

        android:layout_marginStart="8dp" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[Result after rotation 90°](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TpaiB.jpg)

The rotation worked well but how to make it permanent and perform a full rotation in 4 clicks?

Comment: @Benoit TH : Thank you so much, i try now to add a variable " angleposition "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you're always telling the View to rotate from 0 to 90, not 90 to 180, etc.
Something you could do is call animate on the view like so:

```
         view.animate().apply{
               rotationBy(90f)
               duration = 1000L
               start()
         }
```